# Simple MySQL add to columns

Tags: mysql

SO I'm trying to add a stack of columns to a table. I did one via myPHPadmin and nabbed the code so I could use it again. The code is:

```
ALTER TABLE `car_emission_index` ADD `p14` DECIMAL( 6, 3 ) NOT NULL ;
```

But when I try to save it I get this:

```
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE  `car_emission_index`  ADD  `p14`  DECIMAL(

 6,  3 
) NOT NULL ;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'ALTERÂ TABLEÂ `car_emission_index`Â ADDÂ `p14`Â DECIMAL(Â 6,Â 3Â )Â NOTÂ NULLÂ
 ' at line 1
```

Being more than a little new to this I've no idea why this would happen. I can't see anything obvious. CAn anyone help out?

Comment: Have you checked MySQL documentation on how to add column????

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`` ALTER TABLE `car_emission_index` ADD COLUMN `p14` DECIMAL(6,3) NOT NULL; ``

Comment: WOrked like a charm. Cheers.